# Processing images via DirectX on WinRT

Tags: image-processing, directx, windows-runtime, shader

My friend trying to find a best way for image processing(rotate, flip, zoom, crop) on WinRT, but WriteableBitmapEx too slow (testing on Surface and WP8). 
I think, he must use WinRT C++ DirectX for writing library, which will process image via shaders and link it to main C# project, but we don't have any example and don't know how do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org) if you want to keep it in C#.

If you dont plan to go on windows phone, Direct2D would be suitable for image processing. Otherwise you have to use Direct3D.